# how to construct tf_tensor without using tensorflow and feed it to my docker server

Tags: c++, client, grpc, tensorflow-serving

I am trying do build a cpp-client to feed my tf_serving_docker image.

The key is to use as little dependencies on tf , tf-serving as possible.

I trained a denoising autoencoder on 1D time traces, the actual shape is 
[1000, 1, 1] corresponding to 1000 data points as float values.

I used this guide to construct a python client:
https://hackernoon.com/how-we-improved-tensorflow-serving-performance-by-over-70-f21b5dad2d98

And trying to convert to cpp code like:
[gRPC-only Tensorflow Serving client in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033952/grpc-only-tensorflow-serving-client-in-c)

https://github.com/Vetal1977/tf_serving_cpp_client/blob/master/src/serving_client.cc

Here he uses images, but i am unsure how to adapt it to my data structure.

```
// create input protobuf for the image
tensorflow::TensorProto proto;
proto.set_dtype(tensorflow::DataType::DT_FLOAT);
proto.add_float_val(data);


proto.mutable_tensor_shape()->add_dim()->set_size(1000);
proto.mutable_tensor_shape()->add_dim()->set_size(1);
proto.mutable_tensor_shape()->add_dim()->set_size(1);
// initialize prediction service inputs
google::protobuf::Map<std::string, tensorflow::TensorProto>& 
inputs = *predictRequest.mutable_inputs();
inputs["input_traces"] = proto;

// issue gRPC call to the service
Status status = stub_->Predict(&context, predictRequest, 
&response);
```

Somehow i need to user std vectors but i cant find or understand the needed proto.ad_????? function

Answer (score 0):

I found this:
https://github.com/tobegit3hub/tensorflow_template_application/blob/master/cpp_predict_client/sparse_predict_client.cc

And modified my code as in the example.

```
predictRequest.mutable_model_spec()->set_name(model_name);

// create input protobuf for the image
tensorflow::TensorProto proto;
proto.set_dtype(tensorflow::DataType::DT_FLOAT);

for (int i = 0; i > data.size(); i++)
{
  proto.add_float_val(data.at(i));
}


proto.mutable_tensor_shape()->add_dim()->set_size(1000);
proto.mutable_tensor_shape()->add_dim()->set_size(1);
proto.mutable_tensor_shape()->add_dim()->set_size(1);
// initialize prediction service inputs
google::protobuf::Map<std::string, tensorflow::TensorProto>& inputs = *predictRequest.mutable_inputs();
inputs["input_traces"] = proto;
std::cout << "Generated Proto Tensor OK" << std::endl ;
// issue gRPC call to the service
Status status = stub_->Predict(&context, predictRequest, &response);
```